# jQuery $(this).find and $(this).children not working in this code? if right, tell me reason

Tags: jquery, find, children

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
var commentUrl = 'comment.jsp';

$('.privateTimeline').click(function() {
 $.ajax({
 url: commentUrl,
 type:'post',
  data:{
       no : $(this).find('.no').text()  // working!
 },
 success:function(data){
    if( $(this).children('.comment').is(':hidden') ) {  // not working!
    $(this).find('.comment').slideDown(400);  // not working!
    $(this).find('.comment').html(data);   // not working!
 }
 else {
    $(this).find('.comment').slidUp(400);  // not working!
  }
 });
})

</script>
```

1. I don't know well reason than this code is not working.
2. I want to select privateTimeline's children class node so make event.
3. not work in success function part but $(this) is working in data part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
var $target =$('.privateTimeline');
$target.click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: commentUrl,
        type:'post',
        data:{
            no : $(this).find('.no').text()  // working!
        },
        success:function(data){
           if( $target.children('.comment').is(':hidden') ) {  // not working!
               $target.find('.comment').slideDown(400);  // not working!
               $target.find('.comment').html(data);   // not working!
            }
            else {
                $target.find('.comment').slidUp(400);  // not working!
             }
        }
    });
});
```

In `success:function(data){}`, `$(this)` doesnt point to `$('.privateTimeline')` anymore. So you access it using its unique selector.

Also, you had your closing brackets wrong, so I corrected that for you.

Comment: Doing this will run through the selector many times.  You could store it in a variable to optimize, `var $pTimeline = $(".privateTimeline")` and then use that variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your context has changed inside the `.success()` callback, so `this` refers to something other than the jQuery object you expect it to.

You can do something like this to solve it:

```
var _this = this;
...
, success(function(){
    $(_this).find(".yourClass").yourFunc()
});
```

Or:

```
...
, success((function() {
    $(this).find(".yourClass").yourFunc();
}).bind(this));
```